# ImageMagick get web-optimized pictures

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to get 3 versions of an uploaded picture.

The problem is that the 3 new pictures aren't optimized for web like **Save For Web & Devices** in Photoshop. The difference is big. ImageMagick generates files which are 5 times bigger than a web-optimized picture from Photoshop.

Can you help me to improve this issue?

This is the ImageMagick-Part:

```
exec($imageMagickPath." uploads/foto.jpg -resize 514x uploads/fl-foto.jpg");
exec($imageMagickPath." uploads/fl-foto.jpg -resize 320x320 uploads/hl-foto.jpg");
exec($imageMagickPath." uploads/fl-foto.jpg -resize x96 -gravity center -crop 96x96+0+0 +repage uploads/th-foto.jpg");
```

Of course, I want to use these 3 images on the front-end, but they are to big and slow down the entire page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagemagick uses the parameter `-quality #` to set the desired quality, by which you can decrease your image-size by increasing compression.  You can read more about it at their [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality).  The section about jpeg says this:

> For the JPEG and MPEG image formats, quality is 1 (lowest image
>   quality and highest compression) to 100 (best quality but least
>   effective compression). The default is to use the estimated quality of
>   your input image if it can be determined, otherwise 92. When the
>   quality is greater than 90, then the chroma channels are not
>   downsampled. Use the -sampling-factor option to specify the factors
>   for chroma downsampling.

In your case this would become:

```
exec($imageMagickPath." uploads/foto.jpg -resize 514x -quality 60 uploads/fl-foto.jpg");
```

Comment: Thx. I also stripped the meta-info and profile, after converting to sRGB. NOW I think it's the same as photoshop does. I added "-profile ".$profilepath."sRGB.icc -strip "

Comment: @John Doe Smith: You should not only *'accept'* the best, but also *'upvote'* other answers which are helpful. And for sure the accepted answer usually also deserves an upvote too. Just click the small `^` icon to the left of the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this code.

```
   $im = new Imagick('Penguins.jpg');
   $im->cropImage(300, 300, 0, 0);       
   header("Content-Type: image/png");
   echo $im;
```

if it is not working. would you mind i give your phpinfo?

```
  <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
//Function for image re-size and cropping//
if(isset($_POST))
{
     //Some Settings
    $ThumbSquareSize        = 200; //Thumbnail will be 200x200
    $BigImageMaxSize        = 500; //Image Maximum height or width
    $ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
    $DestinationDirectory   = 'uploads/'; //Upload Directory ends with / (slash)
    $Quality                = 90;

    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] array is not empty
    // "is_uploaded_file" Tells whether the file was uploaded via HTTP POST
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
            die('Something went wrong with Upload!'); // output error when above checks fail.
    }

    // Random number for both file, will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 

    // Elements (values) of $_FILES['ImageFile'] array
    //let's access these values by using their index position
    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])); 
    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // Obtain original image size
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Tmp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
    }

    //PHP getimagesize() function returns height-width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
    //Let's get first two values from image, width and height. list assign values to $CurWidth,$CurHeight
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);
    //Get file extension from Image name, this will be re-added after random name
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

    //remove extension from filename
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName); 

    //Construct a new image name (with random number added) for our new image.
    $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;
    //set the Destination Image
    $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumb name
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; //Name for Big Image

    //Resize image to our Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
    if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {
        //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
        if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
            {
                echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
            }
        /*
        At this point we have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
        We can render image to user's browser or store information in the database
        For demo, we are going to output results on browser.
        */
        echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="uploads/'.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName.'" alt="Thumbnail"></td>';
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="uploads/'.$NewImageName.'" alt="Resized Image"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

        /*
        // Insert info into database table!
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO myImageTable (ImageName, ThumbName, ImgPath)
        VALUES ($DestRandImageName, $thumb_DestRandImageName, 'uploads/')");
        */

    }else{
        die('Resize Error'); //output error
    }
}


// This function will proportionally resize image 
function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight); 
    $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
    $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);
    $NewCanves          = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);

    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees memory   
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
    return true;
    }

}

//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original size!
function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{    
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    if($CurWidth>$CurHeight)
    {
        $y_offset = 0;
        $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
        $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
    }else{
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
        $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
    }

    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize); 
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize, $iSize, $square_size, $square_size))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees memory   
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
    return true;

    }

}
</p>
```